# Is this the cent dollar symbol?

Tags: symbols

> I found: "...peanut butter at 4¢ ..."
>   What the symbol is, and how to write?

[image]

Comment: That is indeed the cent symbol. According to [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html), you can access it using the `textcomp` package: with a vertical stroke, it is `\textcent`; with a diagonal stroke, it is `\textcentoldstyle`.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/15925